# Scroll on hover and text leaping

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

It is possible to scroll behave like a fixed element. I would like to scroll in the element covered the content, not moving all of its width. The problem occurs when the box has the `overflow: hidden`, and `:hover` change `overflow` to `auto`.

[image: as it is, and how I wants it to be]

JSBin for a better understanding of the problem 
https://jsbin.com/gurijinugo/edit?html,css,output

I'm not interested solutions using jquery

Comment: But javascript would be fine?

Comment: yea, solition in JavaScript will be fine :)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nawolefupu/1/edit?html,css,output .... What about save the space for the scrollbar like this

Comment: @DaniP you haven't changed anything

Comment: Check again the link

Comment: What about in css on :hover also increase the element's width by width of the scrollbar? Anyway in your case I would probably use some scrollbar plugin to replace the default scrollbar.

Comment: @DaniP hmmm in this case its working, but my case is more complex and it will be not work. I have in scrolled `div`, a lot of `divs` with diffrents colors.

Comment: @DaniP somethink like this jsbin.com/nawolefupu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Mmmm well that's why you must post the code similar to your actual needs, what about this https://jsbin.com/nutikubice/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I don't use a solution of the commentary added by @DaniP, becouse my problem was more complex. I added a solution if someone had a similar problem. I added a wrapper `div`, which has `position: absolute;` and fixed `width`.
For a better understanding JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/mogavegule/edit?html,css,output